# Unexpected non-void return value in void function / swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
extension VoiceController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    public func tableView(_ chatHistory: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userMessagesData.count
    }
    public func tableView(_ chatHistory: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        func userMessage() -> UITableViewCell {
            let userCell = chatHistory.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userMessage")! as! UITableViewCell
            userCell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.33, blue:0.62, alpha:1.0)
            userCell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
            userCell.textLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            userCell.textLabel!.text = userMessagesData[indexPath.row]
            userCell.textLabel!.textAlignment = .right
            return userCell;
        }
        func botMessage() -> UITableViewCell {
            let botCell = chatHistory.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "botMessage")! as! UITableViewCell
            botCell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.56, blue:0.25, alpha:1.0)
            botCell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
            botCell.textLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            botCell.textLabel!.text = botMessagesData[indexPath.row]
            botCell.textLabel!.textAlignment = .left
            return botCell;
        }
    }
}
```

That is my code. I need to do something for this code to works. If I'll delete one of functions, that will work
I can not understand, how to change my code to work. Please, help

Comment: Why do you *nest* the functions? Why do `func userMessage() -> Int` and `func botMessage() -> Void` return a `UITableViewCell` ?

Comment: If I'll delete one of the functions it will work..

Comment: I just found here, on StackOverflow, that it will work if I'll add -> Void, haven't changed yet. But it not working for me

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
public func tableView(_ chatHistory: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let item = arr[indexPath.row]

    if item.isUser {

        let userCell = chatHistory.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userMessage")! as UITableViewCell
        userCell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.33, blue:0.62, alpha:1.0)
        userCell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
        userCell.textLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        userCell.textLabel!.text = item.messsage
        userCell.textLabel!.textAlignment = .right
        return userCell
    }
    else {

        let botCell = chatHistory.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "botMessage")! as UITableViewCell
        botCell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.33, blue:0.62, alpha:1.0)
        botCell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
        botCell.textLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        botCell.textLabel!.text = item.message
        botCell.textLabel!.textAlignment = .left
        return botCell
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Item { 
  let isUser:Bool
  let message:String 
}
```

Where `arr`

```
var arr = [Item]()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. "Use of unresolved identifier 'arr'; did you mean 'err'?"

Comment: @JaneDoev The code snippet is pseudocode that you'll need to change, depending on how *you determine* whether to display a user message, or a bot message. Say for example the cell at index `2`. (The third cell.) Is that a user message, or a bot message? You need to write code specific to your application that makes that decision.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the same returning type that you declared in your function,

```
func botMessage() -> Void //returns void
```

while you're returning a `UITableViewCell`. replace `Void` with `UITableViewCell`.

Also i have noticed you have sub function that returns `Int` remove that function is unnecessary.

Comment: If I add it, I have an error "Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'" before the last bracket

Comment: @JaneDoev You shouldn't be writing a function _inside_ another function. The `cellForRowAt:` function is expected to return a `UITableViewCell`. You need to figure out, in _that_ function, what kind of cell you want to return, and return it.

Comment: I can not understand, what shall I change